# /bin/sh: cc: command not found

Tags: c++, mingw

I am running MingW32 on Windows 10. When I try to compile my programme using the command:

```
$ make -f Makefile

cc -g -Wall -o runScript.exe abc.o def.o ghi.o -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 #-mwindows
```

I get an error:

```
/bin/sh: cc: command not found
make: ***[runScript.exe] Error 127
```

Will appreciate a solution to this.

Comment: Please elaborate on how you installed the compiler and what shell you are using. In general the compiler is distributed separately from a shell .  (The problem is either that you didn't install the compiler, or you haven't got it on your path, or haven't got `cc` as an alias for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with Makefile not finding cc when using gcc is usually setting CC=gcc.exe (and if needed CXX=g++.exe, you can also specify the full path if you like) either as environment variables or on the make command line like this: `make CC=gcc.exe` (you shouldn't really need to add `-f Makefile` as that's the default).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you comments. It gave me direction. MinGW doesn't come with `cc` so instead of defining it to gcc as an environment variable, I used an easy option making a copy of `g++.exe` to `cc.exe` in `C:\MinGW\bin`. Its working now.

Comment: another plan would be to have your makefile call g++ instead of cc

Answer (score -1):

The error make: cc: Command not found typically means that the compiler cc is not installed or not available in the system's PATH. It seems like your Makefile relies on the cc command, which is usually a symlink to the default C compiler.

You can resolve this by installing a C compiler, such as gcc, on your system. If you're on a Debian-based system like Ubuntu, you can install it by running:

sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential

This will install the necessary packages, including gcc, g++, and other tools needed for compilation. Once installed, try running make again, and it should pick up the correct compiler.